# Where can I host an Access DB and Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to extract data from an Access database (all one table, like a flat file) and translate this into a relational database. Seems like this should be possible to do in Rails. Can anyone tell me where I could host both on the same site? I have almost have this working on my desktop, but would like to put it online in order to better deploy it.

BTW, the data cannot be extracted from this Access table into a CSV because, for whatever reason, Access does not allow CSV files greater than around 63K rows, and this table is bigger.

TIA,
--Rick

Comment: Is this for a one-time export to another database, or does the Access DB need to be updated continually by someone? If this is for continuous use, how will the user update the Access DB?

Comment: Just a one time export; am not concerned about updating the Access DB, just need to be able to open the Access db file and read it.